# A Counting Problem about selecting a President and Vice President for a club

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can a President and Vice President be chosen from a club of 5 girls and 4 boys, if the President and the Vice President must be of different genders?

Answer (score 2):

Male president: 4 options

Female vice president: 5 options

Total $4\cdot 5=20$ possibilities for a male president and a female VP, since for every president there are 5 ways to chose the VP.

Female president: 5 options

Male vice president: 4 options

Total: 20.

Thus overall there are 20+20=40 ways to chose a president and a VP.